# Trouble using Pyglet font in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, pyglet

I'm trying to grab a font from the same folder as the program I'm making and use it as the font for Tkinter stuff.
Previously, I'd just use the font I have installed on my computer, but this isn't an option since this is a program I plan to share.

```
pyglet.font.add_file('testingFont.ttf')
myFont = font.Font(family="testingFont",size=24)
thisIsALabel = tk.Label(text="This is a label",
                        foreground="white",
                        background="black",
                        font=myFont)
```

When I do this, the font just loads as the default. I also tried several things that resulted in the same result. I assume I'm just missing something simple.

If it helps at all, the font file is called testingFont.ttf but the font name is FamIo8

In addition, in my imports:
`import tkinter.font as font`
I'm wondering if that might be affecting anything.

Basically, how can I make `myFont` load the font imported via pyglet?

Comment: Why don't you try `family="Famlo8"` if it is the original name?

Comment: That takes the FamIo8 font from my computer. This needs to be local so people aren't required to install the font to run the program.
Edit: nevermind, I'm silly, never thought to actually uninstall the font from my computer to test.

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: in some question you can see how to get full path to folder with script - ie. `BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` and later use it to creat full path to resources `os.path.join(BASE, 'testingFont.ttf')` or `os.path.join(BASE, "subfolder", 'testingFont.ttf')` - maybe this can help